# Scrolling performance with large datasets on Samsung S2 Native browser

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have recently been developing a mobile site to be run in a mobile browser that displays sports events and betting markets. We have implemented a CSS/Javascript scrolling solution (iScroll was causing us too many issues). We have an All Games page that displays 2 markets for every event in the database. Initially we are loading in 15 events (around 30 markets), and then as the user reaches the bottom of the page loading in another 15. Once we load in the third lot of 15 (ie page 3) we remove page 1; when we load in page 4 we remove page 2 etc, so we only ever have 2 pages of data in the DOM at once. This works fine on the iPhone but the scrolling on Samsung devices using the native browser (particularly the S2) is slowing down the more pages we load. It also seems that when the user scrolls back up (and the newer pages are removed, and the older ones loaded in again) the scrolling speeds up again, and is fine by the time the user is back on page 2 and page 1.

Generally, I know the native browser in the Samsungs (especially S2) are slower at rendering, executing javascript etc, and our HTML is more complex than it should be (a constraint of the framework we have inherited). Is there anything else obvious about the Samsungs that could be affecting this?

Just for background, we are using Ruby on Rails, JQuery and CSS (our JS and CSS files are minified and we've removed everything that isn't necessary). I've also done a run through the code and checked for memory leaks.

Thanks